# Email Composer how to send email in INTEL XDK(Cordova)?

Tags: cordova, email, composer-php

why this doesn't send email?

```
(function()
    {
     "use strict";
     function register_event_handlers()
     {
        $(document).on("click", ".uib_w_6", function(evt)
        {
           window.plugin.EmailComposer.open({
                    to:      ['**@gmail.com'],
                    cc:      ['***@gmail.com'],
                    subject: 'Hello World!',
                    body:    'TEST',
                });
        });

        }
     document.addEventListener("app.Ready", register_event_handlers, false);
    })();
```